# Accelerometer on Moto G is bad from factory?

Tags: sensors, proximity-sensor, motorola, motorola-moto-g, magnetometer

I got a Motorola Moto G a few weeks ago and unfortunately it came with what I suspect is a failing accelerometer. I say that because when I open any level (bubble) application it reads random numbers in a wide range, even after the app calibration and on a flat surface (no sensor calibration on the phone settings). 
Let me show you the video to make it easier to understand: http://youtu.be/FD35Uk4HmXo 
I tried four different applications and all of them show the same symptoms- the bubble moving randomly in almost one full degree. When I talked to Motorola technicians they blamed the application(s), so they recommended me to return the phone and get a new one. To my surprise the new device (the one shown in the video) does the same exact thing!
Now I wonder, do I have bad luck and got two defective Moto G? Or they messed up and put a bad sensor in the devices? Or I am doing something wrong!?
Does anyone have this issue with their own Moto G? 
Thanks :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can see in the video, the fluctuations are within about 1° in the first app, and 0.5° in the second. That's not exactly "random numbers in a wide range".

Accuracy within 1° is acceptable for most intended use cases: Mobile games, screen orientation, gestures, etc. It's quite possible that Motorola decided to use a cheaper sensor since the phone itself is intended to be a very low-cost device.

I wouldn't say that it's defective. Possibly subpar, but not defective.

Comment: I never thought about it that way- Motorola using sensors of bad quality regardless the price has never crossed my mind. Unfortunately, like I also explained technical support, this is a tool I use very frequently at work and I can't afford this sensor to be this variable (not even in the half degree application). Now, I really believe in that word you used: subpar! Thanks for your answer, dotVezz!!!!

Comment: If the answer helped you, feel free to mark it as accepted and upvote it if you haven't already =)

Comment: Cool, in another stack exchange site I had to wait for like 24 hours before accepting an answer. Thanks!!!