# Apps go portrait and then landscape unexpectedly

Tags: applications, android-10, operating-system

When I updated my Motorola Moto G9 Plus to Android 10, when going landscape watching videos or playing videogames (after some minutes, repeatedly) go portrait and after 1 to 3 seconds return to landscape, I thought was just my phone, but my wife's phone (Motorola Moto G8 Plus) also have this glitch/bug

How can I fix that?

This was not happening with Android 9.

Comment: wasted bounty, for absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I believe the easiest way for you to avoid that would be to [disable auto-rotate](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6006961?hl=en) in your phone.

The automatic rotation tool is very sensitive, based on accelerometer, and some users complain that [Motorola's is not so good](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60647/accelerometer-on-moto-g-is-bad-from-factory). You may try also to calibrate it using an app like [Accelerometer Calibration Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=redpi.apps.accelerometercalibrationfree) or maybe following the tips on [this tutorial](https://www.nextpit.com/how-to-calibrate-sensors-on-android-smartphones).

Comment: When a forced "landscape" app is open, there is no way that autorotate can do anything. So it is not the problem

Comment: And how does the calibration app I suggested worked for you?

Comment: Didn't work at all. Everything goes the same, is not a problem of motorola accelerometer, is a problem of android, android 9 does not glitch.

Comment: Android 9 goes perfectly fine, I wish I could downgrade my phone. Though Android 10 were better and this thing happened, even if I am portrait like Chrome or Facebook, happens the same, even if I am not doing anything, glitch happens.

Comment: Is there a possibility of your phone being too overloaded and causing the system to be responding the accelerometer changes too slowly? Its a guess, but...

Comment: Accelerometer works as expected, if I put my phone horizontally it goes landscape, and vertically it goes portrait, is not a fault of accelerometer. I am pretty sure is a fault of OS, that because (saying again) in Android 9 neved had this problem, and I was using the same apps and games.

Comment: Well, that's why I though your cell could be overloaded. You said you had this issue with videos and games - they are pretty demanding on phone's resources, and a new OS most of the times requires better hardware. I do have a Moto G8 power with Android 10, and I don't see this kind of issue - I am aware, however, that my device is not a high end one, so I keep it without demanding apps. If the cell is overloaded, the system might take more time to respond, causing glitches. It is, as I said, a guess, since I don't reproduce this issue...

Comment: YouTube, WhatsApp, are demanding apps?

Comment: Glitch happens with any app, does not matter if its just a simple text editor, or image viewer, anything.